# Ошибки: error C2296: ^: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип

Tags: c++

Я написал программу к заданию: 
Разработать алгоритм и составить по нему программу для вычисления 
значений функции z = f(x,y) в зависимости от попадания точки с координатами (х,у) в 
область D. Область D выделена серым цветом.

[image: img]

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 

using std::cout; 
using std::cin; 
using std::endl; 

void main() 
{ 
    float x, y, z, d, e; 
    cout<<" z= "; 
    cin>> z; 
    if (y >= 0 && x >= -2 && x <= 2 && y <= 0,25) 
    {
        z = e^x*y; 
        cout << z; 
    }
    else 
    if (x = 0) 
    { 
        z = sin((1/x^2)+y); 
        cout << z; 
    } 
    else 
        cout << "Значение не входит в область определения функции"; 
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Ошибки:
error C2296: ^: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "float"
error C2297: ^: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "float"
error C2296: ^: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "float"

Comment: Оператор `^` в C++ означает вовсе не то, что вы думаете.

Кроме того, вы не инициализируете все переменные кроме `z`. Как вы думаете, какое будет в них значение?

А ещё, `0,25` означает тоже число, в 4 раза меньшее единицы, а применение оператора `,`.

Answer (score 5):

Не плохо бы для начала научиться возводить в степень на с++.  
Это делается **НЕ** так: `e^x`

А еще у вас x,y не принимают ни каких значений. то есть вы их обьявили, и ни чего им не присвоили. Я бы посоветовал вам обратиться к преподавателю...

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то ^ - оператор. Есть такой в С++. Но его значение совсем другое, чем Вы думаете.
Если нужно возвести какое-то число в степень, то прошу обратить внимание на стандартную библиотечную функцию [`exp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/). Немного подумав, с ее помощью легко научиться возводить любое число в любую степень. Либо можно напрямую задействовать функцию [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)

Comment: ... а вместо `^2` лучше просто умножить число на себя